# How to view Image and update in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

**index.php**

This is my insert page

```
<tr><td><label>Select Photo</label></td>
<td><input type="file" name="image" class="ed"></td></tr>
```

**inset.php**

This is my insert page

```
include('config.php');
if (!isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) 
{
    echo "";
}
else
{
    $file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
    $image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"photos/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);          
    $location="photos/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
    $save=mysql_query("INSERT INTO photos (location)VALUES ('$location')");
    header("location: index.php");
    exit();     
}
?>
```

**view.php**

This is my view page code

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);        
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("display");
$query = "select  * from photos" ;   
$run = mysql_query($query);   
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($run)){
    $location= $row[1];
?> 
<td><?php echo '<img width="100px" height="100px" 
src="'.$row['location'].'">'; ?> </td>
```

I don't know how to update image file and I tried some code but the image file is not changed and the previous image does not display.

Comment: What's in the PHP error log? Is it a database problem? Is it a filesystem permission problem? Is the disk full? If you manually output your queries, are they what you expect? Do they run manually?

Comment: What happens if I upload an image named myfile.php which contains something malicious and then I hit yoursite.com/photos/myfile.php

Comment: Do you really want the script to continue running if config.php isn't found? If not, use require instead of include. mysql_* has been deprecated a long time and you are going to have a very bad time.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);        
   mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
   mysql_select_db("display");
   $query = "select  * from photos" ;   
   $run = mysql_query($query);   
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($run)){
      $location= $row['location'];
   ?> 
   <td><?php echo '<img width="100px" height="100px" 
   src="'.$location.'">'; ?> </td>
<?php } ?>
```

Here you can try with this code. It may helps You.